# NSAlert - how can I present a view as a sheet and get a return value in Swift3?

Tags: cocoa, swift3, macos-sierra

I have the following code working ok:

```
 func alertDialog(question: String, text: String) -> Bool {
    let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = question
    alert.informativeText = text
    alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.warning
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Yes Please")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "No Thank You")
     changedItem = false
  return alert.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn
```

I check the value of `NSAlertFirstButtonReturn` like this:

```
 func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        print (#function, "changedItem", changedItem!)
        if changedItem == true {
            let answer = alertDialog(question: "Save your changes?", text: "Unsaved changes will be shredded.")
            print(#function, "answer: ", answer)
            if answer == true {
                print(#function, "TRUE")
                saveChanges(self)
                changedItem = false
            }
        }
```

I'm struggling to perform the same function, but show the alert as a sheet.

I cannot figure how to present and test the result. I'm currently getting all true or all false.

I've tried various permutations such as follows with no joy, and would appreciate any help.

```
//instead of the return sheetModal

        var result: Int! = 0
        //result = false
        alert.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: { (NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) -> Void in
            if NSAlertFirstButtonReturn.hashValue  == 1000 {
                result = 1
            } else {
                result = 0
            }


        })
         print(#function, "NSAlertFirstButtonReturn: ", NSAlertFirstButtonReturn.hashValue)
        changedItem = false

        if result == 1 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the `runModal` method `beginSheetModal(for:completionHandler:)` works asynchronously. It is impossible to return a value from a function / method including an asynchronous task.

Add a completion handler to the `alertDialog` method:

```
func alertDialog(question: String, text: String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->() ) {
    let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = question
    alert.informativeText = text
    alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.warning
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Yes Please")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "No Thank You")
    changedItem = false
    alert.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: { result in
        completion(result == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn)
    })
}
```

And use the method:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
{
    print (#function, "changedItem", changedItem!)
    if changedItem == true {
        alertDialog(question: "Save your changes?", text: "Unsaved changes will be shredded.", completion: { [unowned self] answer in
            print(#function, "answer: ", answer)
            if answer == true {
                print(#function, "TRUE")
                self.saveChanges(self)
                self.changedItem = false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The functionality is practically the same but the execution is asynchronous.

Side-note: Why is `changedItem` optional? It seems to be a real `Bool` with just **two** states.

Comment: Good point on changedItem. I appreciate your in depth answer as well. About to try it out

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much